# Delete filters from Fiori ABAP backend

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I tried to delete line from `it_filter_select_options` but don't know how. Is there any method to do that?

My URI passes the value in filter but sometimes in some specific conditions I don't want to filter with it, but at the same time I want to filter with others values.

```
if foo = 'xyz'.

  delete it_filter_select_options where property = 'foo'.

  call method /iwbep/cl_mgw_data_util=>filtering
    exporting
      it_select_options = it_filter_select_options
    changing
      ct_data = et_entityset.
endif.
```

gives this syntax error at line `delete it_filter_select_options where property = 'foo'.`:

> field can't be changed

Comment: this filter parameter is deprecated, [avoid using it](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/01/avoid-using-deprecated-sap-gateway-apis-in-your-odata-service-implementation/)

Answer (score 1):

> IMPORTING defines input parameters. When the method is called, an appropriate actual parameter must be specified for every non-optional input parameter. The content of the actual parameter is passed to the input parameter when the call is made. **The content of an input parameter for which pass-by-reference is defined ***cannot be changed*** in the method.**[[1]](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapmethods_general.htm)

Save the filter select options in an local table.

`Data(lt_select_options) = io_tech_request_context->get_filter( )->get_filter_select_options( ).`

Now you can modify the `lt_select_options`.

```
if foo = 'xyz'
"delete lt_select_options[ property = 'foo' ]-select_options[ sign = 'I' ].
delete it_select_options where property = 'foo'.
call method /iwbep/cl_mgw_data_util=>filtering
  exporting
   it_select_options = lt_select_options
  changing
   ct_data = et_entityset.
endif.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use `io_tech_request_context->get_filter( )->get_filter_select_options( )`.
2. Uncheck the filter checkbox for the fields you don't want to be able to filter. (see Transaction `SEGW`, double-click your relevant OData entity)
3. Don't evaluate the filters you don't want in the situations you mean programmatically.